# Iterate over Python list and convert Python date to human readable string

Tags: python

I have a python list that stores IP addresses, hostnames and dates.

I need to iterate over this list and convert the python dates to human readable dates.

How can I iterate over the list and convert the dates to human readable strings?

List:

```
{'_id': '192.168.1.5', '192.168.1.5', 'u_updated_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 1, 20, 27, 38, 364000), 'u_hostname': 'test.example.com'}, {'_id': '192.168.1.3', 'u_ipv4': '192.168.1.3', 'u_updated_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 2, 9, 40, 5, 347000), 'u_hostname': test.test.com}, {'_id': '192.168.1.8', 'u_ipv4': '192.168.1.8', 'u_updated_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 2, 13, 13, 5, 403000), 'u_hostname': hosttest.example.com}
```

Comment: Are you sure that is your list? That's not the correct syntax for a dictionary

Comment: Looks like it dictionary.

Comment: `'_id': '192.168.1.5', '192.168.1.5'` this isn't correct syntax for a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate by the list and modify / add datetime to human-readable:

```
for row_id, row in enumerate(your_list):
    your_list[row_id]['human_readable_date'] = row['u_updated_timestamp'].strftime("specify-your-format")
```

You can find datetime formats [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

Answer (score 0):

If those are real python datetime.date objects you can simply call

```
date.isoformat()
```

This should return '2016-26-09' (today).
Your 'list' does not look like a list tho...